# Передача метода класса в другой метод и в QMap, с++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
class XM : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit XM(  QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void login();

private:
    quint32 counter;
    typedef void(XM::*callback)(quint32);
    QMap<qint32, callback > commands;
    quint32 send(callback cb);
    void login_cb();

private slots:
    void ready();

};


void XM::login()
{
    this->send(&XM::login_cb);
}

quint32 XM::send(callback cb)
{
    // тут отправили задачу на сервер
    this->commands.insert(this->counter, cb);
    this->counter+=2;
}

void XM::ready(quint32 counter, quint32 data)
{
    // тут приняли ответ
    callback fut = this->commands.take(counter);
    fut(data);
}

void XM::login_cb(quint32 data)
{
    // тут нужен тот же this, что был в login
    qDebug() << data;
}
```

Вот такой код, если выкинуть всё мясо.

Ошибка

```
ошибка: called object type 'XM::callback' (aka 'void (XM::*)(quint32)') is not a function or function pointer
```

Comment: commands.take(counter) это вызов фунции_члена объекта  QMap<qint32, callback >, а  с левой стороны у вас указатель на функцию_член  класса  XM. Естественно, что это ошибочное присваивание. Не думаю, что классу понадобится  хранить указатель на свой член...

Comment: Ну я положил функцию в мап, можно туда же положить this, но не нужно так как он уже есть в ready. Вот в том то и вопрос - как запустить

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вообще хотел через QPromise делать, но нужна qt6, а через QFuture не получилось

Comment: без передачи метода можно сделать, но я тогда не смогу делать несколько запросов к одному ресурсу....

Comment: честно говоря я с QT знаком очень поверхностно(не интересует), но  для того, чтобы вызвать соответствующую функцию_член по какому либо ключу, я бы подумал о способе проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вызова не статического метода нужен объект, поэтому просто пишите так:

```
void XM::ready(quint32 counter, quint32 data)
{
    // тут приняли ответ
    (this->*(commands.take(counter)))(data);
}
```

Во вторых, сигнатуры объявленных методов не соответствуют сигнатуре в определении. В частности `XM::login_cb` не имеет аргумента, а вы определяете ее как с одним аргументом.То же самое касается и слоту `ready`. Просто пересмотрите внимательно.

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Comment: Пожалуйста, и извините, что отвечаю с задержкой. Просто занят не только участием в SO

Comment: этот вопрос я думал провисит неделю до первого поленого ответа

Comment: Да, тут вопросы часто скучные бывают, потому многие проявляют пассивность. Надеемся, что в этом плане будут изменения к лучшему...